# Multi-features modeling based on one binary-feature which is rarely 1 (imbalanced data) when there is a cost

Tags: python-3.x, feature-selection, multiclass-classification, imbalanced-data

I need to model a multi-variate time-series data to predict a binary-target which is rarely 1 (imbalanced data). 
This means that we want to model based on one feature is binary (outbreak), rarely 1?
All of the features are binary and rarely 1.
What is the suggested solution?

This features has an effect on cost function based on the following cost function. We want to know prepared or not prepared if the cost is the same as following.

**Problem Definition:**
Model based on outbreak which is rarely 1.

Prepared or not prepared to avoid the outbreak of a disease and the cost of outbreak is 20 times of preparation

cost of each day(next day):
cost=20*outbreak*!prepared+prepared

Model:prepare(prepare for next day)for outbreak  for which days?

Questions:

- Build a model to predict outbreaks?
- Report the cost estimation for every year

[csv file is uploaded](https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AACDSfemDIkf1i44ej4c7N8TMsGUV6ua_VI) and data is for end of the day
The csv file contains rows which each row is a day with its different features some of them are binary and last feature is outbreak which is rarely 1 and a main features considering in the cost.

Comment: As your goal seems to be supervised prediction, why did you use the tag cluster analysis?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060350/anony-mousse] because there is no info about preparation

Comment: But so is "Monday". What would prevent the clustering from clustering Mondays vs. other days? You have a specific situation in mind, even when unobserved you should use a tailored model instead.

Comment: but preparation is important in cost function

Comment: Then just optimize the cost function now?

Comment: The available info about problem definition and requested results are written above

Comment: by the way the question should be in https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You are describing class imbalance.

Typical approach is to generate balanced training data
by repeatedly running through examples containing
your (rare) positive class,
and each time choosing a new random sample
from the negative class.

Also, pay attention to your cost function.
You wouldn't want to reward a simple model
for always choosing the majority class.

Comment: You are right! I have uploaded the csv file and cost function! the cost is 20 times when the rarely features become 1! Since this is for a disease although preparation for disease is costly, rarely occurrence of breakout is 20 times more costly!                                                                       
Therefore a simple model does not fit well since its cost is high

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

**Supervised Approach**

- `SMOTE` for upsampling
- `Xgboost` by tuning `scale_pos_weight`
- replicate minority class eg:10 times
- Try to use ensemble tree algorithms, trying to generate a linear surface is risky for your case.
- Since your data is time series you can generate days with minority class just before real disease happened. For example you have minority class at 2010-07-20. Last observations before that time is 2010-06-27. You can generate observations by slightly changing variance as 2010-07-15, 2010-07-18 etc.

**Unsupervised Approach**

- Try Anomaly Detection algorithms. Such as `IsolationForest` (try extended version of it also).
- Cluster your observations check minority class becomes a cluster itself or not. If its successful you can label your data with cluster names (cluster1, cluster2, cluster3 etc) then train a decision tree to see split patterns. (`Kmeans` + `DecisionTreeClassifier`)

**Model Evaluation**

Set up a cost matrix. Do not use confusion matrix precision etc directly. You can find further information about cost matrix in here: http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Cost_Matrix

Note:

According to OP's question in comments groupby year could be done like this:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df.groupby(df["date"].dt.year).mean()
```

You can use other aggregators also (mean, sum, count, etc)

Comment: I edited the answer. Dont forget to upvote & accept :)

Comment: Check this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html and for filtering: df[df["OutBreak"] == 1]